# iperf error:only position independent executables (PIE) are supported

Tags: android, iperf

I am using iperf for testing to android Application.

The Server and client side communications are configured well. when i send the command from the client side, it shows the following error.

error: only position independent executables (PIE) are supported.

can you guide me to resolve this error?.

Thanks
Balamurugan.S

Comment: Compile with -fPIE flag

Comment: @AlexHoppus i added these lines when compile LOCAL_CFLAGS += -fPIE
LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -fPIE -pie.. even though its showing the same error.

Comment: Try this CFLAGS += -fvisibility=default -fPIE
LDFLAGS += -rdynamic -fPIE -pie